Inverse of a function in ordered pair form
Suppose a bijective function (say $f$) is in an ordered pair form. Then can we write its inverse as
$$f^{-1}= \{(b,a):(a,b) \in f\} \quad ?$$
For example:
Let $f=\{(4,5), (5,6), (3,4), (1,2)\}$. Then,
$$f^{-1}=\{(5,4), (6,5), (4,3), (2,1)\}$$
where $f:\{1,3,4,5\} \to \{2,4,5,6\}$ and $f^{-1}:\{2,4,5,6\} \to \{1,3,4,5\}$.
Will this way of finding inverse of a function work in all cases?

The idea of reversing the $x$ and $y$ coordinates will work, since it's the definition of the inverse function, but in a lot of cases, the function will map between infinite sets, so it won't be realistic to list the ordered pairs. You may, for example, be given a function in closed form, say $y = x^2$ for $x \geq 0$. Because we restricted to the non-negative real numbers, this has an inverse, given by $y = \sqrt{x}$. (If not, I can't write down a two-sided inverse: why?)

Yes.
By definition, we can write
$\begin{align}
(a,b) \in f &\iff f(a) = b \\
&\iff f^{-1}(b) = a \\
&\iff (b,a) \in f^{-1}
\end{align}$
and this is what we wanted to prove.

Thankyou so much
